# WP 8.1 XNA custom game loop (render when dirty?)

Tags: xna, xna-4.0, monogame, windows-phone-8

I need to know whether it's possible to create a XNA game for Windows Phone 8.1 (which I've already) using monogame with a custom game loop.

OpenGL ES has this possibility (GL_RENDERMODE_WHENDIRTY or sth. like that).

Is there anything like that RenderMode for XNA/MonoGame on WP 8.1

**Note:** I'm new to Windows phone game programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1-Create an xaml page
2-Create a new GraphicsDevice
3-Put your own game loop

Comment: You didn't give any details but was helpful to search right things on google :). I created a blank xaml page and added a game view on it using XNAs renderer. I call render() function only when necessary now.

Answer (score 1):

Although I may be misinterpreting your question, you are trying to make a loop that doesn't draw when it does not need to. XNA has this capability.

```
if (needsToDraw == false) {
   this.SuppressDraw();
}
```

The `SuppressDraw()` function is part of the `Game` class (you can [read more at MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.game.suppressdraw.aspx)). In this case, you need to determine if the game needs to be drawn yourself. If it does not, you simply call `SuppressDraw` during the game's `Update` loop.